# Do Spivak, Susskind and Feynman books build a good foundation before starting an undergraduate physics course?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'd like to switch to a physics undergraduate (Bachelor of Science) course next year, until the end of next year I won't be able to do much due to
medical reasons, but I will be able to study for myself.

I would like to do proper preparation work, or even build a bit of
a head start.

Do the following books build a decent foundation and preparation?

- The Feynman lectures on Physics: The New Millennium Edition
- Susskind's Theoretical Minimum 1: Classical Mechanics
- Susskind's Theoretical Minimum 2: Quantum Mechanics
- Susskind's Theoretical Minimum 3: Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory
- Spivak's Calculus

Are there important topics missing that aren't touched by these?

Comment: I thought I'd say as an aside: in my experience, Feynman's lectures books are good as a review of the stuff you already learned or as a supplemental aid. They are excellent at making you reflect deeply on the stuff you learned, but I don't find them good as introductory material. Of course, this is only _personal experience_ from me, so it might not apply to others. Also in my experience, I found that choosing the right book makes a world of difference and it's not actually a trivial task.

Comment: That's actually a very helpful comment, thank you, so it should probably not be the first thing to read. I believe that what is probably missing from the books I listed are exercises to deepen and self-check whether I actually understood the topic. Do you happen to have other recommendations based on your experiences?

Comment: Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts; ergo it is off-topic (cf. [Help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)).

Comment: @KyleKanos if you are talking about the subject, then you are mistaken. What is required by an undergraduate course is not a matter of opinion. So whether a given set of books prepares for that or not is also not an entirely opinion based question.

Comment: "*What is required by an undergraduate course*" is **definitely** a matter of opinion.

Comment: Examples of answers with a low portion of opinion would include something like 'Yes they do cover relevant parts of an **bachelor** physics course'  or 'No, they don't prepare for an undergraduate physics course, here are missing topics'. As far as I know, any **bachelor** course has topics that have to be included, is this different for physics? While the question certainly has aspects up for discussion, it certainly allows for non opinion based answers.

Comment: No, the best foundation is just a solid understanding of the basics, like calculus, linear algebra, and mechanics. "Casual" books like Susskind's often strongly mislead readers into thinking they know more than they do, while only giving them the ability to recognize a couple buzzwords.

Comment: If you want to get a head start building a house, you should start with laying the foundation... not trying to build a 5 story prototype out of plywood.

Comment: @JessicaNowak And yet the answer you have accepted starts off with "In my opinion...".

Comment: @knzhou Have you actually read Susskind's books? Or are you just assuming? I have read the first two (after already having a good foundation). I agree that they are not a sufficient source for certain base concepts, especially on the mathematics side. But at the same time I think calling them books that just have buzzwords is inaccurate.

Comment: You should consider the undergraduate Physics programs and Course and textbook descriptions that you find on-line of various university web sites.  Maybe visit some of the schools known for their physics courses such as Caltech, Stanford, MIT, etc.  A good source is individual Physics professors who have taught or are teaching undergraduate physics as they often provide a bibliography of helpful alternative text books or reference books on their own web pages usually found on-line associated with the physics dept. of the school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the books you have mentioned are better suited for reading after you have taken your first courses in the corresponding subjects. They all contain wonderful insights on physics, especially the Feynman lectures really put a lot of physical phenomena into perspective.

However, the Feynman lectures are lecture notes, and in my experience, you get the most out of them after having a basic understanding of the discussed concepts. You should be able to read the first book in the series, though.

If you have no prior exposure to university physics, Susskind's books are probably too advanced - especially vol. 2 and 3, and so are book 2 and 3 in the Feynman series. If this is the case, you might consider a basic introduction to physics like fx Young & Freedman's University Physics. This could be combined with the first book in the Feynman series, so you can get the beautiful intuition of Feynman combined with the ton of exercises and more complete description of basic concepts you find in a standard textbook like Y&F's University physics.

Comment: We shouldn't be encouraging off-topic questions by answering them.

Comment: I was simply trying to help

Comment: I didn't say you were not helpful. I think being helpful is a great thing to do in general. For example, I love tutoring students in physics. But this site has policies against posting homework questions here, so I vote to close those questions and I do not answer them, even though in a different context I would welcome and respond to such a question. I down voted this answer because in this context a question like this is off-topic, and we should not be encouraging going against site policy. It is nothing against you or your willingness to help.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but it still seems relevant to be able to share experiences about litterature, what and how to self-study etc. Isn't there a place on SE for such questions?

Comment: Probably [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)?